# React MySQL and connection data

Tags: mysql, reactjs, security

I would like to use this kind of stuff for my React application ( https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#mysql )

My question is, how can I secure the MySQL host/user/password data? I guess that this data can be found exploring the client page source code?

I would like to connect to a MySQL database to fetch some data, without using an API.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Looks like node-mysql can only run on server part and can't be called from browsers, so it won't work as intended for my React App.